# Why does splitting my $PATH with `read -r -a line` work but not with `while read -r line`?

Tags: bash

Just noticed something strange which I can't quite explain:

When I split my `$PATH` variable using `read -a` everything works fine

```
IFS=: read -r -a lines <<< "$PATH"
for line in "${lines[@]}"; do echo "$line"; done
```

But when I try to do the same using `while ... read` loop, only the first line is printed

```
while IFS=: read -r line; do echo "$line"; done <<< "$PATH"
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the `mapfile` command probably fits better here.

Comment: `IFS` splits the variable into words, not lines.

Comment: But `PATH` *is* a single line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* make this work; switch from using `IFS=:` to using `-d:`, and append a `:` to the end of your input stream:

```
while IFS= read -r -d: line; do echo "$line"; done <<< "$PATH:"
```

The difference is that `IFS` is used to find boundaries between words, but `read -r line` reads into *exactly one* variable, `line`, so it's not looking for multiple words at all. By contrast, `-d` tells each invocation of `read` which character to *stop* at; by default that's a newline, but you can replace it with any other single character. (If that character isn't found, `read` exits with a nonzero status; that's why the standard/idiomatic `while read` loop idiom skips the last line of your file if it isn't correctly terminated by a newline, and why we use `$PATH:` as our input here).

If you ran `IFS=: read -r first second rest`, on the other hand, it would put your *first* PATH entry into `$first`, the second one into `$second`, and the remainder of the line into `$rest`; whereas with `IFS: read -r line`, it's as if you only had a single item, `$rest`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop processes 1 line, it is not a loop. So the complete path is stored in the field `line`.
When you had given more fields, the path would be divided to those fields (and the last field gets the remainder):

```
while IFS=: read -r line field2 field3 otherfields; do echo "$line"; done <<< "$PATH"
```

When you want to avoid an array, you can use

```
while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done <<< "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
```

Comment: Why unnecessarily break support for directory names with newlines? (:trollface:)

Answer (score 1):

It works fine.

Splitting into an array gives an open-ended number of elements, so does what you expect.

Splitting into a single variable does the same thing, but when it runs out of supplied variable names into which to put the data, it's stops splitting and puts the rest into the last one.

Try this:

```
$: IFS=: read -r a b c <<< "$PATH"
$: printf "[%s]\n" "$a" "$b" "$c"
```

You'll get the first PATH element in `$a`, the second in `$b`, and the rest ALL in `$c`.

Does that make it clearer?

c.f. [this guide](https://linuxhint.com/bash_read_command/)

Answer (score 0):

> Why does splitting my $PATH with `read -r -a line` work but not with `while read -r line`?

Because `read -r line` reads *the whole line* and then *after* reading the single whole line then the line is spitt on `IFS`. Because you provided only one variable to `read`, all the line is in that one variable. You could like split the line on the first element and rest of elements:

```
IFS=: read -r part1 rest_of_parts <<<"$line"
```

See [read 1p read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/read.1p.html) the `If there are fewer vars than fields,` part. Note that still `IFS=: read -r -a lines <<< "$PATH"` will fail when `PATH` contains a newline, like so:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/bin       # reset PATH to something short
$ cd /tmp/
$ mkdir temp$'\n'dir         # create a directory with a newline in the name
$ ls -d tem*
'temp'$'\n''dir'/
$ cd temp$'\n'dir
$ printf "%s\n" '#!/bin/bash' 'echo hello world' > script.sh
$ chmod +x ./script.sh       # add a script in that directory
$ export PATH="$PATH:$PWD"   # add that directory to path
$ ./script.sh                # yes. yes, it works
hello world
$ IFS=: read -r -a lines <<< "$PATH"
$ declare -p lines
declare -a lines=([0]="/usr/bin" [1]="/tmp/temp")
#                                              ^^^^ newline and 'dir' is missing
# That is because `read` reads _one line_ and one line only
# _after_ reading that one line that _one line_ is split on IFS
# so any more lines are ignored.
```

You could use a bash extension to `read` `-d` that makes `read` *not* read the whole line, but up until a character (but I needed to ignore `read` exit status, dunno why):

```
$ while IFS= read -r -d':' line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do declare -p line; done < <(printf "%s" "$PATH")
declare -- line="/usr/bin"
declare -- line="/tmp/temp
dir"
```

Note that `<<<` adds a trailing newline, so using that will result in the last element of `PATH` having a newline - as a workaround, in bash you may use process substitution `< <(printf "%s" "$PATH")`.

The real safe solution if using bash is just using `mapfile`/`readarray`:

```
$ mapfile -d: -t lines < <(printf "%s" "$PATH")
$ declare -p lines
declare -a lines=([0]="/usr/bin" [1]=$'/tmp/temp\ndir')
```